# CTRL+R does not hide the Query Result window in SSMS

Tags: ssms, ssms-2012

I just upgraded from SSMS 2005 to 2012.  Previously, I could hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and the Query Results windows would disappear.

After I upgraded to SSMS I ran a query and, out of habit, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.  Nothing happened.  At the bottom of SSMS I noticed that the status bar was reporting "(Ctrl+R) was pressed.  Waiting for the second key of chord..."

After checking out the details of this keyboard shortcut in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx), I found out that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> was suppose to hide the resulting window as I had suspected.  However, my SSMS isn't behaving as documented.

Is there a way that I can restore this keyboard shortcut to hide my Query Result window?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

1. Open the **Tools** menu select **Options...**
2. Under the **Environment** node click on the **Keyboard** node
3. Click the **Reset** button
4. Click **Yes** on the dialog that pops up

That should solve your issue. If not please add a comment [to this thread](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/679651/ssms-ctrl-r-show-hide-results-pane-shortcut-is-missing-on-menu-and-as-functionality) with details about your issue.

Comment: This worked.  The really odd thing is, I did a fresh install and not, techincally, a real upgrade.  I don't recall the installer ever asking to import any settings and, if it did, my SSMS should have behaved as normal.  Regardless, this has fixed my issue.

Comment: @Charles :
Yes, It worked for me.
Thanks 

Up Vote for you !! :)

Comment: This worked for me, too. But I did need to restart SSMS.

Comment: Worked for me in SSMS2014

Comment: This too worked for me. First I checked that the shortcut was still mapped correctly, and it was, so I did this as a fix, and it started working. I had not updated anything, I had just executed a query (and had been using this shortcut while developing and viewing results vs query), and then it stopped working.. Is this a known bug?  cannot find info on 'why' this is happening, but it happens sporadically to me. FWIW - it stopped working when my query threw an error, and it affected the entire SSMS instance (all query windows).

Answer (score 9):

This is missing in SSMS 2016 as well, assign it manually as shown below.
[image: Assign shortcut to show/hide Result Pane]

Comment: ALT+R sounds good while setting the new shortcut, and instead of using **Global** option, **SQL Query Editor** sounds sensible.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, under Keyboard Settings, I searched for `Window.ResultsPane`. My default keyboard shortcut was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, and doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> was not working for me. 
I have set it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and now it's working fine for me. Doing a reset is not a good idea since it would be removing any and all custom settings set by the user.

Answer (score 2):

If the previous answers does not help,

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> this is already set in SSMS 2012.

This one worked for me..

Answer (score 2):

I tried the solution marked as answer and it didn't work with me.
I even tried to uninstall the SSMS and install it back. Nothing was fixed.

Finally I went to the uninstall a program in control panel to see what did I have recently installed, and Voila, **"TinyTake" by MangoApps was holding the `CTRL+R` combination.**

I killed the process and everything went back to normal.
So finally I went to "Startup" in task manager and disabled it.

Comment: Though not quite the answer most people will need from my original question, I understand that this one may help others. I’ll give you an upvote to bump you up the list. Thanks for giving a secondary option. If others aren’t using this tool, maybe they are using others.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the Toolbar -> Customize -> Commands -> Reset All -> (I recommend re-start of SSMS)
This worked for me in  ms sql 2012

Answer (score 1):

In `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v18.2` `(aka. SSMS 18)` you might want to try resetting `keyboard mapping scheme` in `Options -> Environment -> Keyboard -> Keyboard` window by clicking `Reset` button at the top of it with `(Default)` selected in option list.

Before resetting, it had only one option which processed <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> press only in `DMX Query Editor`:

[image: options_1]

After resetting it showed more options which included `SQL Query Editor`:

[image: options_2]

After that, the key shortcut works (Windows 10 1809 x64).

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard / General.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have checked it on my SSMS2012 and it works, but I have clean install.
The reason might be the upgrade from 2005.
You can try re-setting the shortcuts/toolbar settings by

Right-click the Toolbar -> Customize -> Commands -> Reset All -> (I recommend re-start of SSMS)

If it will not help try to assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to "Window.ShowResultsPane" command. I develop an add-in for SSMS - [SSMSBoost](http://www.ssmsboost.com), it has lots of good features and one of small ones is dumping all registered Commands with their shortcuts. So, on my machine I found out <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to be registered in following contexts to same command:

```
SQL Query Editor::Ctrl+R    Window.ShowResultsPane
MDX Query Editor::Ctrl+R    Window.ShowResultsPane
DMX Query Editor::Ctrl+R    Window.ShowResultsPane
XMLA Query Editor::Ctrl+R   Window.ShowResultsPane
```

SSMSBoost will also allow you to re-assign the shortcut to these values, or you can use native SSMS2012 keyboard shortcut editor.