# Ctrl R not working in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

In *SQL Server 2012*, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> not working. Any other shortcuts for that.
Any setting changes available or is there any alternative?

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/735037/ctrl-r-not-working-in-ssms-2012

Comment: (upped) Thanks for this question. This is bizarre - don't the testers at MS use Ctrl+R ?!

Comment: SSMS 2014 has exactly same problem and all the solutions in this thread apply equally to SSMS 2014 as well. A very similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068661/ctrlr-does-not-hide-the-query-result-window-in-ssms) also.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard / General.

In the middle box,

1. Select `Window.ShowResultsPane`
2. Change the `Use new shortcut` dropdown to `SQL Query Editor` (Global did not work for me)
3. Put your cursor in the "Press shortcut keys:" box and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>. You should see the following:

[image]

4. Click Assign and then OK.

Unlike some other changes that still require an SSMS restart to take effect, the change takes effect immediately, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> should start working again.

[I blogged about this three years ago](https://sqlblog.org/2011/07/14/sql-server-v-next-denali-getting-ctrlr-to-work-again).

Answer (score 54):

Another way is to select Default and hit the Reset button.  This worked for me.

[image]

Comment: This also fixed the same problem for SSMS 2014

Comment: @joe This worked for me - thanks. In @AaronBertrand  solution the `Press Shotcut Keys` textbox did not allow me to type any thing - not sure why.

Comment: I had to restart SSMS 2012 to get the change to take effect

Answer (score 18):

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio version 11.0.3128.0 (SSMS 2012).
Started having the above issue for no aparent reason.
Solved like this: click "Tools -> Options". On the options window, open Environment -> Keyboard on the tree. Then, on the right, press the "Reset" button.
Worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio version 12.0.4100.1 (SSMS 2014).
I had the same issue and resolved it by following below steps -

Click "Tools -> Options". 
On the Options window, expand Environment -> Keyboard -> Keyboard. 
Then, in the right side panel, press the "Reset" button.

[image: See the screenshot below -]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Keyboard Settings as mentioned by @aaron and then change the keyboard mapping scheme (first drop down). This gave me back the shortcuts that I am used to like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I am troubled with this after I installed Visual Studio 2015. When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> is pressed in SSMS, instead of opening a query window, SSMS showed up selection page of the VS files. A Reset as posted above revert to SSMS shortcuts.

Thanks for the posts.

--In 'thoughts'...